# Applying image selection from modal into background of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm hoping someone has done this before and has some guidance.

I'm using bootstrap on a site, and right now I have a working modal that loads in a set of pictures, currently 2. This works fine and I have them linked with anchor tags.

However, I'm trying to find the best way to take the selection of the image and once the user clicks it, apply it to the background image css for the container.

SO right now I just have a test image for the background, but basically I want the selection of an image from the modal to create a bgImg variable, so to speak, and apply it to the background of my container div in real time. So this should apply some javascript, but I don't really know what specifically to use. Or for that matter, how to create a variable from the selection and then apply it to CSS.

Basically if I select image 1 from the modal, the modal should close and image one's URL should now take the place of the CSS for the background image url, if that makes sense

CSS for the background in question:

```
.my-container>.middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding:30px;
  background-image: /*this would be the bgImg for the href*/;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML for the modal and the images that I want to apply to the background

Choose Page Background

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Choose an image:</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="bgImg"><img style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="images/bg_orange.svg"></a>
        <a href="bgImg"><img style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="images/bg_green.svg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

adding JS

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 const images = document.querySelectorAll('some-image-selector');
 images.forEach(img => img.addEventListener('click', setBackground));

 function setBackground(e) {
  const container = document.querySelector('.my-container > .middle')
  container.style.background = `url(${e.target.src}) center center no-repeat`
 };

 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to make this work, you'll want to add a click event listener to each image.

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('some-image-selector')
images.forEach(img => img.addEventListener('click', setBackground))
```

something along those lines ^^

Then within `setBackground`, update the css

```
function setBackground(e) {
  const container = document.querySelector('.my-container > .middle')
  container.style.background = `url(${e.target.src}) center center no-repeat`
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this now. Can you check my JS block I added above and make sure my syntax and semicolons are appropriate here?

Comment: looks ok as long as you are in modern browsers.. be sure to rewrite according to whatever you are trying to support.. but should be ok for a PoC in chrome

Comment: Ok I added it but it's not working right now. I should remove the anchor tags from the images right?

Comment: yeah - take the concept that i put forward and adapt it to however your markup is written.  the important thing is to get the image src from the click handler and then transfer that src over.  The anchor tags don't sound necessary though.

Comment: Ok, I got it working by changing 'some-image-selector' to just 'img'. But it's making the page processes insanely slow after I use it,  could it be due to an issue in how the script loads

Comment: if there's a ton of images yes.. depending on how your app behaves you could be adding duplicate event handlers as well.  be sure to clean up those handlers as the modal unmounts or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do this with Javascript. In jQuery:

```
//prevent default action
$('.modal-body a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});


$('.modal-body img').on('click', function(e){
    //store the target url in a variable
    let source = $(this).attr('src');
    console.log(source);
    //set the user-selected image to the proper spot on the page
    $('.my-container > .middle').attr('src', source);
    //now close the modal
    closeModal();               
});


function closeModal(){
    $('#exampleModal').hide();
}
```

You can tweak how you want to close the modal by using a function like `slideToggle()` instead of `hide()`.

Comment: Hmm I'm trying this now but it doesn't seem to have any action when I click on an image

Comment: I didn't read your html correctly. Since you're using <a> tags to wrap your images (probably unnecessary) you have to first prevent the default action of the <a> tag. I set up a basic pen to test and the console log is showing the proper URL. You miht have to tweak the closeModal() function to get the selector right. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKoOBR